# Nginx limit_req_zone size monitoring

Tags: nginx, webserver, throttling, rate-limiting

When using the `limit_req_zone` directive in `nginx` is there a way to monitor the size of a zone? I'm trying to test `nginx`'s behavior once a zone is at capacity.

Tangentially, is there a lifespan on the zone size before it get's flushed? I can't seem to find documentation around that. Or does the zone size limit only apply for concurrent users?